# Does anybody know a zoomable JPanel implementation?

Tags: java, jpanel, zooming

I'm looking for an extended JPanel that scales rendering and mouse events of its children.

I tried to implement it by myself but did not get the event think handled since I can not override the `dispatchEvent()` method because it's final.

I also tried to catch events with `MouseListener`/`MouseMotionListener` and redispatch it to using the `dispatchEvent()` but that gave me a stack overflow and did not solve the problem.

The scaled rendering and layout resizing works fine.

Does anybody know a working implementation of this?

Comment: have you looked at magnifierui class?

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes I did. It does not solve the dispatch event issue. I tried to solve it using a JXLayer UI and also with the new JLayer, but none solved the dispatch issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did with it JXLayer using the [MouseEventUI](https://link-collector.googlecode.com/svn-history/r436/ver2/trunk/labs/zoom-with-jxpanel-src/org/pbjar/jxlayer/plaf/ext/MouseEventUI.java) and overriding the method `AffineTransform getTransform(final JXLayer<? extends V> l)`. My only problem is now that the tooltip and popupmenu positions are not transformed.

I don't know how to trick the ToolTipManager.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact requirements, this might be tricky, but you might want to have a look at https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/07/jxtransformer_t.html (source code at https://java.net/projects/swinghelper ).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this is much worse than my try. It is also discontinued for a long time.

Comment: @Stephan What does jxtransformer not do for you? I have used it successfully for rotating non-square components in the past.

Comment: I got a lot of rendering issues and it did not solve my problem with event transformation.